# Excel - add rows

Tags: excel

Hi I have a sheet of data that is reported by week. For my problem I can only use months. The columns that I have are Month, Value, Week. Weeks are in order, but months repeat: weeks 1 - 3 are in Month 1, weeks 4-7 are in Month 2, etc. In this sheet I need to sum the values by month. How do I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you want the data. Do you just want a value in a cell with the data? Then this formula would work for the following data:

=SUMIF(A:A, A2, B:B)

[image]

If you want this in a more aggregated format, I would use a pivot table referencing this data and making sure to add the Month in as the ROWS and Value as the VALUES (defaults to sum) as pictured:

[image]